# Why does my Boost::ASIO async_read callback only function correctly once?

Tags: c++, asynchronous, networking, client, boost-asio

I've set up a little asio client test project to try find out why my asio read routine only functions correctly first time:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    Network network;

    network.connect("google.com");
    network.request("/search?q=test+search");

    network.connect("example.com");
    network.request("/index.html HTTP/1.1");

    while (1) {}

    return 0;
}
```

It's suppose to allow connecting to a site and then performing requests and waiting asynchronously for a response.

The connect function looks like this:

```
void Network::connect(std::string domain) {
    host = domain;
    socket.close();

    asio::ip::tcp::endpoint endPoint = resolveIP(domain, "80");
    socket.connect(endPoint, ec);
    if (!ec) std::cout << "\n\nConnected to " << domain << " via " << endPoint << ".\n\n";
    else std::cout << "\n\nFailed to connect to " << domain << ", Error code:" << ec.value() << ", message = " << ec.message() << ".\n\n";
}
```

I first call socket.close() to ensure the previous connection is closed when connecting to the second site, should be no problems here; and the resolveIP function works correctly.

In the request function, I first call a GrabData function which implements the asynchronous read callback using async_read with a streambuf to ensure all the data is read in one go.
I then then call run() on my asio::io_context within the main thread after issuing the request to the server and preparing the handler:

```
void Network::GrabData() {
    asio::async_read(socket, buff,
        [&](std::error_code error, std::size_t length) {
            if (error) std::cout << "Async Read error:" << error.message() << "\n\n";

            std::cout << "Handler read:\n\n";
            std::cout << make_string(buff);

            buff.consume(length);
        });
}

void Network::request(std::string request) {
    if (socket.is_open()) {
        GrabData();
        std::string sRequest =  "GET " + request + "\r\n"
                            "HOST: " + host + "\r\n"
                            "Connection: close\r\n\r\n";

        socket.write_some(asio::buffer(sRequest.data(), sRequest.size()), ec);
        if (ec) std::cout << "\nerror:" << ec.message() << "\n";

        context.run();
    }
}
```

What I'm getting is that it retrieves the first sites data correctly and then connects to the second site, though does not retrieve data from the second site, i.e.

```
Connected to google.com via [2a00:1450:4009:81e::200e]:80.

Async Read error:End of file

Handler read:

**page from google**

Connected to example.com via [2606:2800:220:1:248:1893:25c8:1946]:80.
```

I'm aware the async_read function is throwing an error due to it reaching the end of the file, though I'm not sure the point of being able to use a resizable streambuf if it's going to cause an error because you don't know the length of the data.

Also, if I try to call GrabData again, from within the handler as if I wanted to wait for more data to be recieved, I'm greeted with the error message repeating, despite no data coming in to trigger the callback:

```
void Network::GrabData() {
    asio::async_read(socket, buff,
        [&](std::error_code error, std::size_t length) {
            if (error) std::cout << "Async Read error:" << error.message() << "\n\n";

            std::cout << "Handler read:\n\n";
            std::cout << make_string(buff);

            buff.consume(length);
            GrabData();
        });
}
```

Outputs:

```
Connected to google.com via [2a00:1450:4009:81e::200e]:80.

Async Read error:End of file

Handler read:

**page from google**

Async Read error:End of file

Handler read:

Async Read error:End of file

Handler read:

Async Read error:End of file

...
```

As well as consuming the entire streambuf I have also tried error.clear() though this seems to clear the local variable and not the underlying asio EOF error.

Comment: Please post code and output as text not images.  Please read [mcve].

Comment: [io_context::run reference](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_context/run/overload1.html) are you calling `restart` before second `request` invocation  ?

Comment: This seems to indeed have been the problem in regards performing the request to the second server.
I guess to wait for a second 'complete' set of data from the same server, after the same single request, this could also be the more logical way to do this, as opposed to calling the handler repeatedly after the first execution. Thanks